# some of my shortcuts don't work, for example, Shift+Click

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really need help. This shortcut is very helpful for PvP/Skywars or any other war, such as Survival Games, etc. So when I need to get things from a chest, I always take a long time, making me vulnerable to other players! Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Hover mouse over your required item, then press number keys ( below function keys ) to transfer items to your hotbar.

Since you mentioned multiplayer, at start of game you can break chests to instantly collect all items within the chest.